# Flutter SnackBar leaves an invisible padding in the Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar, scaffold

I am showing a log in button in a page. Once the user has logged in, the `SnackBar` will display "Logged In with Google" for example. While the `SnackBar` is still showing, the body of the `Scaffold` is being build to a new page, the one accessible by logged in users. However, building the page while the `Snackbar` is still showing somehow leaves a padding in the Scaffold, in the area used by the `SnackBar`, so the underlying `Scaffold` `body` is still visible, yet you cannot interact with it.  If there is a button at the bottom of that `body`, the button is not tapped because the invisible padding left behind by the (already closed) `SnackBar` blocks the content underneath.

What am I missing? Is there another way to produce the desired result?

[image]

Comment: I have found the problem root cause. If in one page shows a Snackbar and while showing it, the user moves to another page (for example in a bottomNagationBar) the new page is build with the padding issue that I mentioned.

However, if the `SnackBar` disappears before moving to another page, there is no issue. So 'transporting' a visible `SnackBar` to another page produces many issues. Any idea what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the `Scaffold` with a `ScaffoldMessenger` in every page and now seems to work. I will elaborate on the answer later on.